# Pass a parameter to jQuery method while calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I was calling a jQuery method,

```
 $(".the_pt_body").jPaginate();
```

My jPaginate.js is written like this way:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.jPaginate = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
        ----
                ----
        };
        var something=------- ;
   ----------
```

I need to pass a value from the jsp where I am calling the jQuery method.Something like,

```
$(".the_pt_body").jPaginate("Say_any_value");
```

Is this possible?? If yes, how can I get that value in `jPaginate.js`.

Comment: As you can see the function has `options` parameters.
Usually,  in this case the function will later have a part that will replace the values of `defaults` with the values of `options`, so
You can use it like that: `.jPaginate({ property1: 'myValue', pr.. })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass it as options to plugin, like:

```
$(".the_pt_body").jPaginate({option_1: "Say_any_value", option_2: "Second Value"});
```

And in plugin:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.jPaginate = function(options) {
        var defaults = $.extend({
           option_1: "some default value",
           option_2: "default val"        
        }, options);
       var opt_1 = defaults.option_1; //you get Say_any_value
```